# How do I find the array position in which an integer should be inserted in Javascript more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently completed this programming challenge (on FreeCodeCamp):

> Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be
>   inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The
>   returned value should be a number.
>
> For example, getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5) should return 1 because it
>   is greater than 1 (index 0), but less than 2 (index 1).
>
> Likewise, getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19) should return 2 because once the
>   array has been sorted it will look like [3,5,20] and 19 is less than
>   20 (index 2) and greater than 5 (index 1).

My code works, but it seems dreadfully inefficient and probably unnecessarily verbose. I am trying to not just solve the challenges, but also to become a good programmer who writes quality code. In that spirit, I am hoping the Javascript experts on here can give me examples of how this problem can be solved more efficiently.

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  var diff = 0;
  var minDiff = 0;
  var insPos = 0;
  function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  arr.sort(sortNumber);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    diff = num - arr[i];
    if(i === 0 || (diff < minDiff && diff >= 0)){
      minDiff = diff;
      if(arr[i] == num){
        insPos = i;
      }
      else{
        insPos = i + 1; 
      }
    }
  }
  return insPos;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ask this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: study binary-search algorithm :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
function getIndexToIns(num) {
  var diff = 0;
  var minDiff = 0;
  var insPos = 0;  
  arr.sort(sortNumber);
  var pos=-1;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){    
    if(arr[i]>=num){
        pos=i;
        break;
      }
    }
  if(pos>=0){
    alert('Index: ' + pos);
  }else{
    alert('Not Found. Perhaps: at ' + arr.length);
  }
}
  function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num">
<button type="button" onclick=getIndexToIns(document.getElementById('num').value);>Find Pos</button>
```

Comment: I enter 2.3 and it returns index as 3. Should be 2 i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If our input array is sorted, let the items to search for (and insert) be integer or even object, this job is best done by binary search algorithms. Given the input array sorted these are much faster than `indexOf` or `findIndex`. So assuming that the input array is already sorted the following binary search function will return you the searched items index or if not exist it will return a negative integer designating the index of insertion  when negated. So if it returns -3 the search item is missing and should be inserted at index 3 in order not to break the sorting.

PS You will be returned a -0 (negative zero) if the non existent item is to be placed at index 0.

```js
Array.prototype.sortedFindIndex = function(val, cb = x => x) { // default callback for primitive arrays
  var            deli = this.length-1,                         // delta index
                 base = 0,                                     // base to add the delta index
           expectedAt = i => { while (this[i] !== void 0 && cb(this[i]) < val) ++i;
                               return -i};
  while (deli > 0 && cb(this[base + deli]) != val) {
    deli = ~~(deli/2);
    cb(this[base + deli]) < val && (base += deli);
  }
  return cb(this[base + deli]) === val ? base + deli : expectedAt(base + deli);
};

var arr = [{a:0,b:"foo"},{a:1,b:"bar"},{a:2,b:"baz"},{a:3,b:"qux"},{a:4,b:"fox"},{a:5,b:"pun"},{a:6,b:"alf"},{a:7,b:"alf"},{a:8,b:"alf"},{a:9,b:"alf"},{a:10,b:"alf"},{a:11,b:"alf"},{a:13,b:"alf"}],
    brr = [3,6,7,9,13,15,18,21,22,25,29,33,37,42,65],
    idx = arr.sortedFindIndex(12, o => o.a);
console.log(idx);
idx = brr.sortedFindIndex(27);
console.log(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the lowest index three steps should be performed:
1) Add a new element to the existing array;
2) Perform the ascending sort of all the numbers in the new array;
3) Find the index searched for.
This code works if all the elements of the new array are numbers (which is totally enough for this challenge on https://www.freecodecamp.com)

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  var newArr = arr;
  newArr.push(num);  //add a new element num to the end of the array

  function compareNumbers(a,b){
    return a - b;
  }

  var sorted = newArr.sort(compareNumbers); //sort the numbers in the array

  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++)
    {
      if (sorted[i] === num) //index of the element equal to num is the index you are looking for
        {
          return i; 
        }
    }
}
getIndexToIns([2, 20, 10], 19);
```